# Not able to attach file of type .bak in email android development

Tags: android

Not able to attach and send sqllite dbback up file in email.
I have taken backup of my sqllite db file and it is present in internal storage.
Now i have a requirement to send that file via email.

I have written below code which is not working. Please help.

```
    String filelocation = myBackupRestore.GetFilePath(fileName);
    String subject = "Backup from ----- app";
    String shareBody = subject+": \n";
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

THe behavior of any email app is going to be up to the app itself.  They differ from device to device and between email providers.  Unless you're willing to write an email client yourself (and run the email server, as some servers will strip attachments or bock certain ones) there is no way to assure that functionality will work on a particular phone and a particular email provider.